# How to find middle of string to insert a word

Tags: python-3.x, caesar-cipher

I am trying to write a caesar cipher code, but make it harder than normal. The actual encryption is on a file that is then split into lines. For each line, I want to add a word to the beginning, middle, and end before doing the shift. So far I have this but it isn't working:

```
file = str(input("Enter input file:" ""))
my_file = open(file, "r")
file_contents = my_file.read()
#change all "e"s to "zw"s 
    for letter in file_contents:
        if letter == "e":
            file_contents = file_contents.replace(letter, "zw")
#add "hokie" to beginning, middle, and end of each line
    lines = file_contents.split('\n')
        def middle_message(lines, position, word_to_insert):
            lines = lines[:position] + word_to_insert + lines[position:]
            return lines
        message = "hokie" + middle_message(lines, len(lines)/2, "'hokie'") + "hokie"
```

I am getting

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

What am I doing wrong?I thought len() returns an int?

Comment: In Python 3.x, `len(lines) / 2` may not be an integer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using python3

You will need some more optimization even after fixing the len() not being an integer.

Let's work this out first: our word for the example will be :

```
a = 'abcdef'
>>> len(a)
6
>>> len(a) / 2
3.0 #this is your problem, dividing by 2 returns a float number
```

The error you are getting is because float numbers (3.0 and 3.5) can't be used as slice indices in a list (or string), to solve this in this particular case:

```
>>> len(a) // 2
3
```

Now, for optimization:

This code takes a file, which I assume is made of many lines of text, since you are splitting your lines using '\n'.

**When you will have solved the slices part, you will get another error, telling you can't concatenate strings with lists *(you should at this point, try your code with my proposed fix above, so you understand what happens)***

Your middle_message function is made to work with a single string, yet you are passing it your variable 'lines', which is a list of strings.

to test I had to pass it an index of lines:

```
message = "hokie" + middle_message(lines[0], len(lines[0])//2, "hokie") + "hokie"
```

so if you want to work with all the strings in 'lines', a list comprehension loop could be useful, giving you a new list with your modified strings.

```
newlines = ["hokie" + middle_message(lines[x], len(lines[x])//2, "hokie") + "hokie" for x in range(len(lines))]
```

I know, this is longer than 80 characters.. you can work this down I'm sure ;)

now here are the results I get by testing:

```
>>> file_contents
'This is going to be my test file\nfor checking some python cipher program.\ni want to see how it works.\n'

>>> lines
['This is going to bzw my tzwst filzw', 'for chzwcking somzw python ciphzwr program.', 'i want to szwzw how it works.', '']

>>> newlines
['hokieThis is going to hokiebzw my tzwst filzwhokie', 'hokiefor chzwcking somzw phokieython ciphzwr program.hokie', 'hokiei want to szwzhokiew how it works.hokie', 'hokiehokiehokie']
```